# assign variable in puppet

Tags: unix, puppet

I am newbie to puppet, I have code like below in unix

```
log_exts=$(vgdisplay /dev/cassandra|grep Free|awk '{print $5}')

if lvcreate -n lv_cas -l ${log_exts} /dev/cassandra
then
mkfs -v -t ext4 /dev/cassandra/lv_cas
logit "Create LV file system"
fi
```

I want to convert this into puppet.

I should not use **exec** puppet command. so how can I grep for FREE and print the fifth column, then assign logical volume size.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

For this specific thing, you can use `-l 100%FREE` as a size value to assign all free space with `lvcreate`.

On a more fundamental level, if you don't want to use `exec` to get the data, you will have to extend `facter` to get you the data you need.

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.3/custom_facts.html#adding-custom-facts-to-facter

Comment: I do not get what you mean by -l 100%FREE. can you please explain

Comment: Read `man lvcreate`. You don't need to get the number of free extents in your case as `lvcreate -n lv_cas -l 100%FREE /dev/cassandra` will automatically assign all free space to the new volume.

Comment: I tried below two method       $temp= lvcreate -n lv_cas -l 100%FREE /dev/cassandra logical_volume {'lv_cas':
     ensure => present,
    path => '/dev/cassandra'
    size=>$temp
    require =>Volume_group['vg_cas']
    } Even I tried like below

    size => 'lvcreate -n lv_cas -l 100%FREE'

Still I am getting error. when i run lvcreate -n lv_cas -l 100%FREE /dev/cassandra in promet its working only when I assign to variable it is not working

Comment: Let me repeat myself: You should really reconsider your approach. From your question history, I get the strong impression that you neither understand basic Linux system administration nor Puppet and you are just firing random shots in the dark and hope it to work. To successfully use a tool like Puppet, it is absolutely necessary to fully understand what you are trying to do manually, without automation. Understanding how Puppet works is the next step and trying to combine the two is just the last step (which you try to do first).

Answer (score 0):

To manage your logical volumes with Puppet, use an [appropriate module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/lvm).

You may not be able to replicate your current logic 100%. Puppet's paradigms differ from those of shell scripts. Your mileage is usually better if you adjust your workflows to this new premise.